# Setting up simple online database and simple web services for application development

Tags: android, sql, database, web-services

I am currently developing an android application that will communicate it's user's information with a master database through web services. Eventually, I will most likely rent a reliable online database such as `SQL Azure`. However, during development, such a service is not really required - all I need is an online database that my web services can connect to.

My application connectivity flow is as such:

`Android Application > Web Service > Stored Procedure on DB`

For someone who has experience with databases but is inexperienced with web services, what is the most efficient way of setting this up, both easily and at low-cost, just for development purposes?

Comment: Use XAMPP server, it is free and you can develop the database and middle language scripts (like PHP), then when you finish your developing your project you can use `SQL Azure` to host the database and the scripts.

Comment: If you requirements for logic on the server is low, then have a look at https://parse.com/